# Dynamic Feature Module google services issue when more than one DFM is added

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am working on modularizing our app and implementing Android's new Dynamic Feature Modules for on-demand downloads. I was able to add feature1 successfully, however, when I add feature2, i get this error:

```
[:feature1, :feature2] all package the same library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-license].
[:feature1, :feature2] all package the same library [com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license].

Multiple APKs packaging the same library can cause runtime errors.
Adding the above library as a dependency of the base module will resolve this
issue by packaging the library with the base APK instead.
```

The only thing my DFMs use as dependencies is `:app`. When I look for these license dependencies, they do not exist in any of my gradle files. We currently use android gradle version 3.5.2. Here are snippets of dependencies for the `:app` module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.4'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-beta-3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.60"
}
```

How do i resolve this issue? I'm assuming it must be due to one of the google services dependencies containing the same thing as each other, i.e. `play-core`, `gms`, and `firebase`, but I have no idea. The documentation says that DFM's must depend on your base module (in my case, `:app`), so this seems odd to me. Any help figuring this out would be super appreciated.

Thanks~

edit: both feature1 and feature2 have two dependencies: the required plugin `apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'` and `implementation project(':app')`

Comment: what it means is your feature 1 as well as feature 2 is bringing the same library but your base module i.e app is not having that library so while packaging, it doesn't know which version should be taken. So to fix it you must add the particular library to your app gradle

Comment: The only dependencies both features bring in that the base module does not have is `apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'`

Comment: can you post dependencies of your feature 1 and 2? They might be using the different version of mentioned dependencies

Comment: edited post to include dependencies

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After doing some experimenting and digging into the dependency structure of my DFM's, i realized that I had to include a separate `google.json` file in the DFM. Once I added that, gradle no longer complained about duplicate licensing.